# Extracting the type keyof'd in a generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

Is there any way to extract the `T` type from a function type of `<K extends keyof T>(k: K) => T[K]`

```
type T = { a: 'a'; b: 'b' }
type Fn = <K extends keyof T>(k: K) => T[K]

// This results in the return types being 'any'
type ValueOfT = Fn extends (k: keyof infer U) => any ? U : never


// This throws a compiler error
type ValueOfT2 = Fn extends <K extends keyof infer U>(k: K) => U[K]
  ? U
  : never


// Type isn't narrowed
type NotNarrowed = Fn extends (k: 'a') => infer U ? U : never
// so can't do this
type FnTypes = Fn extends (a: infer U) => any ? U : never
type ValueOfT3 = { [K in FnTypes]: Fn extends (a: K) => infer U ? U : never }
```

Comment: Don't think this is possible

Comment: I agree that this isn't going to happen for you.  It would require a higher order type inference which the compiler [doesn't currently do](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30887) and [might not do anytime soon](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31811#issuecomment-500058205) and is possibly [too complex](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606).

Comment: Maybe you can explain more about your use case and someone can suggest an alternative that does work?